# Problem with manipulating global variable within function in bash

Tags: bash, function, stack, subshell

Code is to match '(' with ')' and '{' with '}'. My problem is that the way I did is request to pop() is creating subshell. Is there a way to modify it with locale -n or some new features from bash 4.3> ?

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
top=0
STACK_SIZE=4
declare -a contents

read -rp "Enter parentheses: " input

if [ -z "$input" ]; then
echo "no input"
exit 1
fi

make_empty() {
top=0
}

is_empty() {
[ "$top" -eq 0 ] && return 0 || return 1
}

is_full() {
[ "$top" -eq "$STACK_SIZE" ] && return 0 || return 1
}

push() {
if is_full; then
    echo "Stack overflow"
    exit 1
else
    contents[$top]="$1"
    ((top++))
fi
}

pop() { #problematic function
if is_empty; then
    echo "parentheses arent matched"
    exit 1
else
    ((top--)) #this is the line that doesnt update $top var
    echo "${contents[$top]}" #but updates local copy of top inside its subshell
fi
}

i=${#input}

while read -n 1 char; do
    case $char in
        } | { | \( | \));;
        *) echo "wrong input"
           exit 1;;
    esac
((i--))
if [ "$char" == '(' ] || [ "$char" == "{" ]; then
    push "$char"
elif [ "$char" == ')' ] && [ "$(pop)" != '(' ]; then #here unintentional subshell creation
    echo "not nested properly"
elif [ "$char" == '}' ] && [ "$(pop)" != '{' ]; then #same here
    echo "not nested properly"
elif [ "$i" -eq 0 ]; then
    if is_empty; then
    echo "matched"
    break
    else
    echo "Not nested properly"
    fi
fi

done <<<"$input"
```

**input/output**:

```
+ top=0
+ STACK_SIZE=4
+ declare -a contents
+ read -rp 'Enter parentheses: ' input
Enter parentheses: () #INPUT
+ '[' -z '()' ']'
+ i=2
+ read -n 1 char
+ case $char in
+ (( i-- ))
+ '[' '(' == '(' ']'
+ push '('
+ is_full
+ '[' 0 -eq 4 ']'
+ return 1
+ contents[$top]='('
+ (( top++ )) # TOP IS 1 NOW
+ read -n 1 char
+ case $char in
+ (( i-- ))
+ '[' ')' == '(' ']'
+ '[' ')' == '{' ']'
+ '[' ')' == ')' ']'
++ pop
++ is_empty
++ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
++ return 1
++ (( top-- )) #TOP SHOULD BE 0 AFTER THIS
++ echo '('
+ '[' '(' '!=' '(' ']'
+ '[' ')' == '}' ']'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ is_empty
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']' #TOP IS NOT UPDATED HERE
+ return 1
+ echo 'Not nested properly'
Not nested properly
+ read -n 1 char
+ case $char in
+ echo 'wrong input'
wrong input
+ exit 1
```

I commented the code to pinpoint the lines where the problem is.
I solved the problem by rewriting the code from scratch but would like to see if its possible to do something with this subshell creation.

Working UPDATED CODE:

```
#set -x
top=0
STACK_SIZE=4
declare -a contents

read -rp "Enter parentheses: " input

if [ -z "$input" ]; then
    echo "no input"
    exit 1
fi

make_empty() {
    top=0
}

is_empty() {
    [ "$top" -eq 0 ] && return 0 || return 1
}

is_full() {
    [ "$top" -eq "$STACK_SIZE" ] && return 0 || return 1
}

push() {
    if is_full; then
        echo "Stack overflow"
        exit 1
    else
        contents[$top]="$1"
        ((top++))
    fi
}

pop() {
    if is_empty; then
        echo "Parentheses aren't matched"
        exit 1
    else
        ((top--))
    fi
}

i=0
while [ "$i" -lt "${#input}" ]; do
    char="${input:$i:1}"

    if [ "$char" == '(' ] || [ "$char" == '{' ]; then
       push "$char"
    elif [ "$char" == ')' ]; then
         if [ "$top" -eq 0 ] || [ \
            "${contents[$((top-1))]}" != '(' ]; then
             echo "not nested properly"
             exit 1
          else
             pop
          fi
     elif [ "$char" == '}' ]; then
          if [ "$top" -eq 0 ] || [ \
             "${contents[$((top-1))]}" != '{' ]; then
              echo "not nested properly"
              exit 1
           else
              pop
           fi
     else
            echo "wrong input"
            exit 1
     fi
((i++))
done

is_empty && echo "matched" || echo "Not nested properly"
```

Comment: @TimRoberts agreed but I have to retrieve from pop and compare with literal. How to do that in this context without breaking the structure? Lexicographical suggestion accepted and corrected :)

Comment: I was wrong, my apologies.  I'm rethinking it.

Comment: Your analysis is correct.  There's no way to do a `$(function)` call with side effects.

Comment: Be aware that correct code can have unbalanced `{(`. An example is your code: `if [ "$char" == '(' ] || [ "$char" == "{" ]; then`.

Comment: Off-topic: An alternative is checking `echo "$input" | sed 's/[^{()}]//g;:a;s/\(()\|{}\)//;ta'`, where an empty string is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the design of `pop`. You are doing two unrelated things at the same time: Printing some information message, and then using the message to detect the outcome of `pop`. The latter could be done using an status code, but it would mean that you should pass to `pop` the expected popped element::

```
pop() { # unproblematic function
  local expected=$1
  if is_empty; then
    echo "parentheses arent matched" 1>&2
    return 2
  else
    ((top--)) #this is the line that doesnt update $top var
    if [[ $expected == ${contents[$top]} ]]
    then
      return 0
    else
      echo "not nested properly" 1>&2
      return 1
    fi
  fi
fi
```

}

and use it as

```
# Matching parentheses
declare -A matching
matching[')']='('
matching[']']='['

if [[ "(){}" == *$char* ]]; then
  echo "Wrong input: $char" 1>&2
elif [ "$char" == '(' ] || [ "$char" == "{" ]; then
  push "$char"
elif pop ${matching[$char]}; then
  : No error with pop ...
else
  : pop error ...
fi
```

Note that the semantics of `pop ${matching[$char]}` is like your original `pop`, but it also verifies that popped character.

Answer (score 1):

Using nameref (`declare -n`) :

```
pop() { 
    declare -n local_var=$1
    if is_empty; then
        echo "parentheses aren't matched" >&2
        return 1
    else
        local_var="${contents[--top]}"
    fi
}
```

To use it, instead of `[ "$(pop)" != '(' ]`, call like this :

```
pop var && [ "$var" != '(' ]
```

Comment: I think you should do `pop char && [ "$char" != '(' ]`

Comment: Interesting. Using this approach, you can make a `capture_output()` function with parameters `call_this_function` and `store_output_in_this_var`.  The capture_output() can use a named pipe including `mktemp` and `rm tmpfile` for capturing the output of a function like `pop()` and return the variable. That way you can also call functions that you can not change.

Answer (score 1):

Catching the output of a subshell is hard.
You can try using a temporary file (or a named pipe), but you would like to make a function for the redirect to, reading from temp file and removing that file. And with this new function, you will have the same problem, how to get the output of that function into a variable.
Changing the `pop()` function is a possibility, as given in some other answers.
When you don't want to change your `pop()`, you can use

```
elif [ "$char" == ')' ] && pop > /dev/null && [ "${contents[$top]}" != '(' ]; then
```

The redirection `> /dev/null` is because of the `echo "${contents[$top]}"` in `pop()`.

When you do want to make some more small changes in your code, remove the `echo` from `pop()` and consider using `case "$char"`:

```
case "$char" in
  '('|'{')
    push "$char"
    ;;
  ')')
    pop && [ "${contents[$top]}" != '(' ] || echo "not nested properly"
    ;;
  '}')
    pop && [ "${contents[$top]}" != '{' ] || echo "not nested properly"
    ;;
  *)
    if [ "$i" -eq 0 ]; then
      if is_empty; then
        echo "matched"
        break
      else
        echo "Not nested properly"
      fi
    fi
    ;;
  esac
```

Comment: I already changed the requests to pop check the updated code. Doing via temp files was one of the tasks if I couldnt make the code work.

Comment: Your updated code is roughly the same. I call `pop()` first, that way I do not need to subtract one from `$top` when accessing the contents array.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to modify it with locale -n or some new features from bash 4.3> ?

No.

The only way is to implement *inter-process communication*, where the parent would listen for messages from child processes and act on them. This would be a lot of work.